# NS-2 (Network Simulator) error getting TCP window: "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."

Tags: tcl, ns2

I'm trying to follow a Network Simulator tutorial using NS-2 version 2.35 on Ubuntu, but I can't seem to see the TCP window size and the error I get seems useless. The code:

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp set window_ 1

# This fails!
puts [$tcp window]
# So does this:
#puts [$tcp window_]
```

The output:

```
    (_o10 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o10 cmd window"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o10" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$tcp window"
    invoked from within
"puts [$tcp window]"
    (file "window-test.tcl" line 8)
```

How do I fix this problem and output the TCP window size? More generally, is there a way to get more useful errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/otcl/doc/tutorial.html), you use the `set` method to *both* write *and read* from instance variables, depending on how many arguments you give it. This is just like the base Tcl `set` command (though that doesn't really know about instance variables). Thus, in your case you might do:

```
puts [$tcp set window_]
```